# Setting up the logic for a Login Screen in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, android-jetpack-compose, data-class

So for this project, I am setting up a Login Screen that logs into a database that is suppose to validate the email. It's my first time actually doing something like this. I have made a login page with firebase. But this time im tring to login to an Azure DB. Here are some code for better clarification

Here's the API

```
@Singleton
interface MMRApi {

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST(LOGIN_EP)
    suspend fun sendLoginInfo(
        @Field("EmailId") emailId: String,
        @Field("MobileMakeModel") mobileMake: String
    ): Response<LoginCreds>
}
```

Here's the Request and Response Fields

```
//Request Data Class    
data class LoginCreds(
        @SerializedName("EmailId") val emailId: String,
        @SerializedName("MobileMakeModel") var mobileModel: String
    ){
        companion object{
            const val PLATFORM = "Android"
        }
    
     private fun getModel(): String{
         return "$PLATFORM ${Build.MODEL}".also { mobileModel = it }
     }
    
    }

//Response Data Class

    data class LoginResponse(
        @SerializedName("data") val data: List<DataInfo>,
        @SerializedName("status") val status: Int,
        @SerializedName("message") val message: String
    ){
        override fun toString(): String {
            return "\n" +
                    "List of Data: $data" +
                    "Status: $status" +
                    "Message:$message"
        }
    }
    
    data class DataInfo(
        @SerializedName("Id") val id: Int,
        @SerializedName("CustomerId") val customerId: String,
        @SerializedName("UserAttributeId") val userAttributeId: Int,
        @SerializedName("Enabled") val enabled: Boolean
    ){
    
        override fun toString(): String {
            return "\n" +
                    "Id: $id" +
                    "CustomerId: $customerId" +
                    "UserAttributeId: $userAttributeId" +
                    "Enabled: $enabled"
        }
    
    }
```

The Repository

```
class MMRRepository @Inject constructor(private val api: MMRApi) {

    suspend fun postLogin(emailId: String, mobileMake: String): Response<LoginCreds>{
        return api.sendLoginInfo(emailId, mobileMake)
    }
}
```

The ViewModel

```
@HiltViewModel
class LoginViewModel @Inject constructor(private val repository: MMRRepository)
    : ViewModel() {

    val loginPostResponse: MutableLiveData<Response<LoginCreds>> = MutableLiveData()

    fun pushLogin(emailId: String, mobileMake: String){
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val response = repository.postLogin(emailId, mobileMake)
            loginPostResponse.postValue(response)
        }
    }
}
```

The Composable

```
@Composable
fun MMRLoginScreen(navController: NavController, loginViewModel: LoginViewModel = hiltViewModel()){
    var emailId by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf("") }

    Surface(modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .padding(top = 65.dp)
    ) {
        Column(
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Top,
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        ) {
            Image(
                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.parabit_logo_orange_blue),
                contentDescription = stringResource(R.string.company_logo_string),
                contentScale = ContentScale.Fit,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .width(225.dp)
                    .height(95.dp)
                    .padding(top = 43.dp)
                )

            Text(
                text = "MMR Bluetooth Access Control",
                color = Color(0xFFF47B20),
                fontWeight = Bold,
                fontSize = 18.sp,
            )
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))

            LoginField(loading = false){
                loginViewModel.pushLogin(emailId = it, mobileMake = Build.MODEL)
                navController.navigate(MMRScreens.MainScreen.name)
            }

        }
    }

}

@OptIn(ExperimentalComposeUiApi::class)
@Composable
fun LoginField(
    loading: Boolean = false,
    onDone: (String) -> Unit = {email ->}
){
    val email = rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf("") }
    val keyboardController = LocalSoftwareKeyboardController.current
    val valid = remember(email.value){
        email.value.trim().isNotEmpty()
    }

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        EmailInput(
            emailState = email,
        )

        SubmitButton(
            textId = "Login",
            loading = loading,
            validInputs = valid
        ){
            onDone(email.value.trim())
            keyboardController?.hide()
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun SubmitButton(
    textId: String,
    loading: Boolean,
    validInputs: Boolean,
    onClick: () -> Unit
) {

    Button(
        onClick = onClick,
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(3.dp)
            .fillMaxWidth(),
        enabled = !loading && validInputs,
        colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(Color(0xFFF47B20))
    ) {
        if (loading) CircularProgressIndicator(modifier = Modifier.size(25.dp))
        else Text(text = textId, modifier = Modifier.padding(5.dp))
    }

}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Can you please clarify what is the issue and what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Well the general login logic. I haven't been using `POST` with my projects and this is the first time I am using it. I know with `POST` there's a `Request` and a `Response`. So being able to use create the logic for Logging in that way, if that makes sense.

Comment: Microsoft Docs has an Authentication process connecting to Azure  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/enable-authentication-android-app?tabs=kotlin this will be the best example on the Kotlin Setup with Azure with all the redirects to establish a connection.

Comment: I appreciate it, but there's got to be a simpler way of doing the Login Authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it was a simple. First i had to set up the API to send the two fields I need in order to get a response.

```
@Singleton
interface MMRApi {
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST(LOGIN_EP)
    suspend fun sendLoginInfo(
        @Field("EmailId") emailId: String,
        @Field("MobileMakeModel") mobileMake: String
    ): LoginResponse
}
```

The `LoginResponse` data class is used to store the response of the API once the input field goes through. Then for the instance, You set it up where the instance is used to tell you if the email worked.

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
class AppModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideLoginApi(): MMRApi{
        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                //Used to pick up the responses for the API Calls
            .client(
                    OkHttpClient.Builder().also { client ->
                        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
                            val logging = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
                            logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY)
                            client.addInterceptor(logging)
                        }
                }.connectTimeout(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                        .readTimeout(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                        .build()
            )
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
            .create(MMRApi::class.java)
    }



}
```

Everything else was standard and I was able to get the Login Authentication to work